# How to load localization strings from JSON in iOS

Tags: ios, localization

I have a service that will return JSON of key/value pairs of localized strings.  This data can change, so I was looking to set up a call to this service to get the latest localization strings.

Since, I will not be bundling the localization string with the app.
Should I build the .string file pragmatically on update?
Or insert the records into Core Data?

Just looking for the best solution for performance.

Thank you

Comment: Definitely core data, it generally suits all object persistence needs

Comment: I actually found this https://github.com/Lolloz89/DMLocalizedString which uses json files and reads the NSDictionary from memory.  A good option, but may go with Core Data because the Api service will be giving a delta change of the localizations.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try, this can be useful and reduce much of your code: [`MCLocalization`](https://github.com/Baglan/MCLocalization)